# Trouble finding my Android app on Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I just posted my first app to the Android market about half an hour ago (pretty stoked, really, but that's neither here nor there :p). The issue I'm running into is that I can't find it on the playstore. I've searched on my computer with all devices selected, as well as on my phone and tablet - which I used to test the app before publishing.

I've tried going directly to the link with https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ptrprograms.asteroidbelt

I can also supply my manifest file if that's necessary. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes a while to get propagated through their system. Wait a few hours, it'll show up.

Comment: Oh OK. I had thought it was instant. Thank you very much!

Comment: It drives me nuts every time I do a new release, wanting to test it out... For a completely new program, I don't know for sure, but it'll show up.

Answer (score 0):

When did you post your app? Take in consideration that there are many apps that may have a similar name so you have to scroll many pages down and it takes a lot of time to make the app available. Try to search the app using you account name in no more than 3 days. Maybe tomorrow... My friends had the same problem and they just waited.